# Style react installed react components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-component

I downloaded a react `multiselect component` from a user who designed it by himself. I installed it with `npm install ....` and only call that component in my react code with `<MultiSelect .../>`. This is a Dropdown checkbox 'menu' and I wanna change for example the font-color to another color. But the dude I got that component from styled the color `inline` (saw this when expecting the code in a browser) and even if I set a `div` container around the call of his component and set `color: red` in my css it isn't working.

Another problem is that I want to style the Input field of the dropdown in another color than checkboxes which are dropping down. And both are a `span` with a `className`. Is there a way to set different colors for different classNames for the installed components? I havent found a way to do it right now...

for better understanding I briefly explain the layout of the dropdown menu:  the first thing you see a field where you can click on and then the checkboxes will dropdown. If you click on a checkbox, the name of the checkbox will appear in the upper field. If you click close dropdown, the dropdown will close and you only see the name selected checkboxes in the field (both are a span container). And I want to design the field and the droped down checkboxes in another color.

I hope you get my problem and can help.

Cheers

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Try styling MultiSelect by component name or by a given class name with "!important" this way:

```
MultiSelect {
   color: red !important;
 }
```